# 'UserInput' is defined but never used no-unused-vars 'UserOutput' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, reactjs

newbie to react, following a series of lecture 
***i just trying to excute this simple code but something went wrong and gave me error like* 'UserInput' is defined but never used* although path and src sets perfectly ok ***

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import  UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component() {

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>some random text</p>
      <userInput />
      <userOutput /> 
    </div>

  );
}
}
export default App;
```

***UserInput.js***

```
import React from 'react';
const userInput = () => {

return <input type="text" />;
};
export default userInput;
```

***UserOutput.js***

```
import React from 'react';

const userOutput = () => {

return(<div>
    <button>hello </button> 
    </div>)


};
export default userOutput;
```

Comment: `import  UserInput` small `u`, just a typo

Comment: In your app.js change`<userInput />` to `<UserInput />` and `<userOutput />` to `<UserOutput />`

Comment: You should use what you import. `UserInput !== userInput`. Also you can import with any name you want if you have to import any default export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Improvement**

Define `class App extends Component{}` not `class App extends Component(){}`

Define imported `UserInput`,`UserInput`  like

```
      <UserInput />
      <UserOutput />
```

App.js

```
import  UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component{

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>some random text</p>
      <UserInput />
      <UserOutput /> 
    </div>
  );
}}
export default App;
```

Live demo for your code [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-river-uc2ww)

Comment: Thanks vahid! i just want to know the difference between ```Component()``` and simple ```Component```?

Comment: @FaisalNadeem You can use parenthesis with function only here component is like class.